# Can some one help me to fix this random matrix

Tags: c#, memory, matrix

The problem is this matrix shows one sign repeated 3 times, I need only show signs 2 times,
if someone can help me would be great.
I need this for memory game.

```
Random rand = new Random();

string[,] Matrix = { { "!", "!", "@", "@" }, { "$", "$", "#", "#" }, { "%", "%", "^", "^" }, { "&", "&", "*", "*" } };

int row = 0;
int column = 0;

int row2 = 0;
int column2 = 0;

for (int inc = 0; inc < 51; inc++)
{
    row2 = rand.Next(4);
    column2 = rand.Next(4);

    Matrix[row, column] = Matrix[row2, column2];

    row = row2;
    column = column2;
}


Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n       {0} |  {1} |  {2} |  {3}", Matrix[0, 0], Matrix[0, 1], Matrix[0, 2], Matrix[0, 3]);
Console.WriteLine("     ----|----|----|----");
Console.WriteLine("       {0} |  {1} |  {2} |  {3}", Matrix[1, 0], Matrix[1, 1], Matrix[1, 2], Matrix[1, 3]);
Console.WriteLine("     ----|----|----|----");
Console.WriteLine("       {0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", Matrix[2, 0], Matrix[2, 1], Matrix[2, 2], Matrix[2, 3]);
Console.WriteLine("     ----|----|----|----");
Console.WriteLine("       {0}|  {1}|  {2}|  {3} \n", Matrix[3, 0], Matrix[3, 1], Matrix[3, 2], Matrix[3, 3]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? what do you mean by one sign is repeated three times?

Comment: how to fix it, I need only show signs 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix you can replace the following code:

```
Matrix[row, column] = Matrix[row2, column2];
```

with

```
char c = Matrix[row, column];
Matrix[row, column] = Matrix[row2, column2];
Matrix[row2, column2] = c;
```

In your original code you're loosing the value at `Matrix[row, column]`, while you have to swap it with value at `[row2, column2]`.

Comment: thanks you soo much this fix my problem. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, u're developing "find the pair" game for memory training?
I'would like to recomment u rework algorithm.
U can use this statement for generating small random numbers:
1)
    `int randomNumber = DateTime.Now.Ticks % 4`
or
2)
    `int randomNumber = rand.Next(100000) % 4;`

NOTE: If u want to get help with reworking algorithm, I can help u.

Comment: yeah, I am developing "Find the pair", thanks for the help and the offer but I want to create without help if possible.